# Regular Expression to remove \n outside of curly bracket

Tags: python, regex

How to match \n outside of curly bracket ?
for example here's the string:

```
{{ sometext...\n sometext... }}\nsomemoretext...\nsomemoretext...\n
```

I want to use re.sub to remove the \n outside of the curly bracket
but I can't figure out the regex, can someone help me on this ?
any help will be appreciated greatly, thanks

Comment: .strip() might take it out too, unless you specifically want to use regex for some reason (they're fatter though)

Comment: @sihrc strip only remove the \n from the start and end of the string, but I want to match the \n outside of the curly bracket, so I guess using regex is the best solution, haha

Comment: Oh! sorry about that, I misread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your curly braces are balanced, you could use a *Negative Lookahead* to do this.

```
>>> re.sub(r'\n(?![^{]*\})', '', text)
```

See [**Working Demo**](https://eval.in/156663)

Comment: it works !!!
thanks a bunch hwnd, lookahead is a new things to me, will learn it to understand your regex,